# Is it okay to set a cookie with a HTTP GET request?

Tags: http, cookies, get, httpwebrequest, request

This might be a bit of an ethical question, but I'm having quite a discussion in the office about the following issue:

Is it okay to set a cookie with a HTTP GET request? Because whenever a HTTP request *changes* something in the application, you should use a POST request. HTTP GET should only be used to retrieve data identified by the Request-URI.

In this case, the application doesn't change, but because the cookie is altered, the user might get a different experience when the page loads again, meaning that the HTTP GET request changed the application behaviour (nothing changed server-side though).

[Get request reference](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3)

The discussion started because we want to use a normal anchor element to set a cookie.

Comment: some years later... but I think the issue is when changing the response content based on cookies, not so much about setting cookies themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with GETs, especially if they are on an a tag, is when they get spidered by the likes of Google.

In your case, you'd needlessly be creating cookies that will, more than likely, never get used.

I'd also argue that the GET rule it's not really about changing the application, more about changing data.  I appreciate the subtle distinction with the cookie ( i.e. you are not changing data on YOUR system ), but generally, it's a good rule to have, and irrespective of where the data is stored, GET shouldn't really be used to change it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the side-effects when the site is being crawled by Google. On the other hand, isn't that their issue?

Comment: Yeah, but whatcha gonna do?  You can deny them spidering with robots.txt, but then you end up not having (parts of) your site indexed. Easiest thing is to keep changes as POSTs, hence the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

The user can always have *different experience* when he issues another GET request - you do not expect to return always the same set of data for (imagined) time service: "GET /time/current".

Also, it is not said you are not allowed to change server-side state in response for GET requests - it's perfectly 'legal' to increase a page hit counter, for example, even if you store it in the database.

Consider the section [9.1.1 Safe Methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)

> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not
>   generate side-effects as a result of performing a GET request; in
>   fact, some dynamic resources consider that a feature. The important
>   distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects, so
>   therefore cannot be held accountable for them.

Also I would say it is perfectly acceptable to change or set a cookie in response for the GET request because you just *return some data*.

Comment: I do not totally agree, because the user actually does request the side effects. The user clicks a link to specifically set a setting which we keep in the cookie.